# Обращение к прототипу выдаёт ошибку «is not a function»

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, что не так. После обращения к прототипу `Weather.geton` выдаётся ошибка «is not a function». В функциональном стиле всё работает без ошибок.

```
 function Weather(url) {
        this.geton(url);
        console.log(url);
    }

    Weather.prototype.geton = function(url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true );
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                if (status === 200) {
                    this.successH(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    this.errorH(status)
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }

    Weather.prototype.successH = function(data) {
        if (typeof data == 'string') {
            return;
        } else {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }

    Weather.prototype.errorH = function(err) {
        return
    }
```

Comment: `this` внутри `xhr.onload = function() {` не тот же самый что снаружи

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` внутри обработчика `onload` ссылается на объект `XMLHttpRequest`, а у него нет методов `successH` и `errorH`.

Исправить можно например сохранив ссылку на нужный объект до onload и используя ее вместо `this`, например

```
Weather.prototype.geton = function(url) {

    var self = this,
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('get', url, true );
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            self.successH(xhr.response);
        } else {
            self.errorH(status)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Либо использовать [стрелочные функции из ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
Weather.prototype.geton = function(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('get', url, true );
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            this.successH(xhr.response);
        } else {
            this.errorH(status)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Еще вариант с [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
Weather.prototype.geton = function(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('get', url, true );
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function (){
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            this.successH(xhr.response);
        } else {
            this.errorH(status)
        }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: @PavelMayorov, fixed :)

Comment: Большое спасибо,  все работает!